# Give user permission to change priority of an IRQ/root process

Tags: linux, process, root, priority, irq

Is it possible, in Linux, to allow an user to change the priority of a process owned by root? More specifically an IRQ process?

For an embedded real-time application I want to raise the priority of the GPIO IRQs because that led to better results. However these are owned by root. It would be nice if raising the priorities of the root processes would be possible without using root privileges.

Comment: To set process priorities in the Linux (or UNIX) kernel directly, you need to use the [real-time scheduler](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10165). The indirect method is to use the process' `nice` value. I can think of two solutions in both cases: Configuring `sudo` so that the user can run `renice` or real-time commands under a different identity. The other is to give the user the [CAP_SYS_NICE capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Both solutions will allow the user to modify priorities of *all* processes.

Comment: So, when I take your description literally ("without using root privileges"), CAP_SYS_NICE seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is write a specific tool that will do that for me.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    setuid(0);
    system("renice <params>");
}
```

I compile and install in `/usr/bin`.

Set owner to root if not already:

```
chown root /usr/bin/my-renice
```

Then I change the permissions with:

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/my-renice
```

That first `4` bit tells the binary to execute with the owner's permission
(`root`, as we set above) regardless of who calls it. 
See `man setuid` for more info.

Note that is not 100% secure if you have users who have access to that computer who should not be able to run that renice.

Especially: **do not pass through any command line parameters to the `system()` call.**

```
system(argv[1]);   // <-- definitely a total security breach!
```

I find this solution the simplest on computers where I just have a few processes and only a few users who are trustworthy.